# Backpropagation chain rule example

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

My question is in regards to an [MIT course example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrMHA3yX_QI).

[image: NN Schematic]

The instructor delves into the backpropagation of this simple NN.

[image: NN with derivative chain and equations]

I have two questions.

1. Why do we seem to disregard the weights of the second layer (in blue)?
2. The red circle, should this not be $\partial y_2$ (followed by $\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial P_3}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why do we seem to disregard the weights of the second layer (in blue)?
  -----because activation function is after that block, so differential with the o/p y is as good as with the weight.
- The red circle, should this not be ∂y2 (followed by ∂y2∂P3)?
  -----y2 and y1 is the o/p of the same block i.e. both must be same

Comment: Wow thanks, I feel silly now. Thanks again!